# How to fetch the values from java List

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need your help in fetching the values from a List and to append them to an insert statement. I am having a class called Employee that:

```
public class Employee {
    private Integer id; //Getter and Setter
    private String name;//Getter and Setter
    private String remarks;//Getter and Setter
    private boolean disable;//Getter and Setter

public Employee(Integer id, String name,  String remarks, boolean disable){
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.remarks=remarks;
            this.disable=disable;
    }
```

In the bean, I am generating random number for the employeeList:

```
private List<Employee> employeeList;

private List<Employee> selectedEmployees;

public test() {
        super();
        employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        employeeList.add(new Employee(i, "Name " + i, "Remarks " + i, true));
    }

}
```

And the selected values will be stored in the List `selectedEmployees`. Now I want to write a new method to print the fetched values and then to append them to an insert statement to insert the selected values into a table.

```
public void updateRecords() {
    System.out.println("Size =" + selectedEmployees.size());
    //Here I need help to print the values of the list and then to append them to an insert statement to the table employees

insert into employees (id,name,remarks) values ();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `for each` statement to reach that, however because you have declared your member variables `private` you can't read them so either you should declare your class members `public` or declare getters to read member data

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
for(Employee e:selectedEmployees)
{
   System.out.println("Employee id: "+e.id+" name: " + e.name+ " remarks: " + e.remarks);
   String sql = "INSERT INTO employees (id,name,remarks) VALUES(?,?,?);";
   PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
   statement.setInt(1, e.id);
   statement.setString(2, e.name);
   statement.setString(3, e.remarks);
   statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: invites SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

For arraylist you would use this syntax. X being the number of that employee in the list then you would have to create getters and setter for your variables.

```
 Employees.get(x).getName ();
```

You would then create an employ object then insert like so.

```
  Employee dude = new employee(1, name, remarks,   disable); 

  Employees.add(dude);
```

Comment: this solution has nothing to do with what has been asked, please read carefully

Answer (score 0):

[PreparedStatement#executeBatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) is perfect candidate to solve your problem.

You can implement it like this:

```
public void updateRecords(List<Employee> employees) {
    System.out.println("Size =" + selectedEmployees.size());
    //Here I need help to print the values of the list and then to append them   to an insert statement to the table employees

  String query = "insert into employees (id,name,remarks) values (?,?,?)";

  Connection con = ... // establish DB connection
  PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
  for(Employee emp : employees) {
      ps.setNumber(1, emp.getId());
      ps.setString(2, emp.getName());
      ps.setString(3, emp.getRemarks());          
      ps.addBatch();
  }

  ps.executeBatch();

}
```

Above code is just an example you need to make it compilable and also need to do proper exception handling.

Hope this helps.